# Is it safe to create your own QUERY BUILDER like Symfony in AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, sql-injection

I am making a query inside a controller that sends the table name, the condition like `WHERE` clause etc.. In my SERVICE in order to create a QUERY.

**studentController.js**

```
let student_ctr = this;

let em = default_service.query();
em.columns('*')
em.from('user_accounts', 'o')
em.innerJoin('user_accounts_credentials', 'uac', 'uac.user_id = o.uuid')
em.getResult({
    controller: student_ctr,
    variable: 'get_user_account'
});


console.log(student_ctr.get_user_account);
```

NOTICE: inside the `em.getResult()` I sent the controller `student_ctr` and a variable `get_user_account` to create a scope variable (You can see it inside the defaultService on how I made this into a scope variable). Is it okay to pass a whole object of the controller? just out of curiousity.

**defaultService.js**

```
let path = 'app/base/model/defaultModel?_='; // Sends all Common Query

return {
     query: () => {
          let sql = ' SELECT ';

          let columns = a => string += a;
          let from = (a, b) => string += ' FROM ' + a + ' AS ' + b;
          let leftJoin = (a, b, c) => string += ' LEFT JOIN '  + a + ' AS ' + b + ' ON ' + c;
          let getResult = o => {
              $http({
                   url: path + 'query',
                   method: "POST",
                   data: { q: string } // Sends the SQL string to the defaultModel.php
              })
              .then(response => {
                   let name= o.variable;
                   let model = $parse(name);
                   model.assign(o.controller, response.message); // I am going to create a scope variable.
              })
          }
     
          return { columns, from, leftJoin, getResult }
     }
}
```

With all this, I create an SQL string `SELECT * FROM user_accounts AS o INNER JOIN user_accounts_credentials AS uac ON uac.user_id = o.uuid`.

I find this very helpful, fast, neat. Although inside my `DOM's Network > Header` a USER can actually see the string being passed inside the defaultModel.php.

After all that ease I got, I just wonder if it is safe or not.

### UPDATE

I am asking if it is safe if there were hackers or something that might manipulate my database just by exposing the string inside the DOM > NETWORK > HEADERS passed to the defaultModel.php

Comment: So you ask if it's ok to pass the SQL directly to the PHP? If you don't mind giving the client control over your database sure go for it. Jokes aside this sounds like a very bad idea because you don't control what query gets executed anymore, is it a select? is it a drop statement? the server doesn't know and will just execute everything.

Comment: A quick select, I guess. Although, I am planning to create not just a SELECT Statement but also an INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE Statement. I am literaly going to make it as dynamic as possible. inserting a where clause, order by etc.. I am asking if it is safe if there were hackers or something that might manipulate my database just by exposing the string inside the DOM > NETWORK > HEADERS passed to the PHP

Comment: No, it is not safe all it takes is for someone to notice you are passing a SQL query to that endpoint and then them opening Postman and submit their own.

Comment: If its a client side, will it be fine? or what if I just pass parts of the parameters and create the string inside the php?

Comment: or is there any way to hide it?

Comment: There is no way to hide what url your posting from front end.

Comment: You can, however, pass data to the backend and create the query there, I suggest you looking into graphQl if you want to query your backend in a safe way with more dynamic results

Comment: @FlorentinStemate, How is GraphQL immune to code injection? I know it's not SQL, so by definition it can't be susceptible to SQL injection. But if the back-end allows arbitrary input to be executed as a GraphQL query, how is that any better?

Comment: @BillKarwin Well I am not very experienced with GraphQL I only recommended it as an alternative to his idea: to decide what data you want in the frontend. 

But since you asked: to my knowledge you don't pass it a random string that gets evaluated as code, but merely some params in a JSON like format. You are also able to define types, fields, and mutation so you can provide only the data and actions (delete, create, etc.) you want. ....

Comment: .... Saying that I am also aware that without proper configuration this thing can do more harm than good (not adding a limit on how many results one can query at a time or by not setting a nesting limit you are opening yourself to denial of service attacks).
And regarding your last point: I think that every language is vulnerable to code injection if the developer decides to treat unsanitized user input as code

Comment: Fair enough, I should learn more about GraphQL. It's possible that there are safeguards so it's guaranteed to treat values as values, not as code expressions.